# Ways to pass arguments to a function in MS ACCES / VBA

Tags: vba, function, ms-access

I am currently struggling to understand someone else's code in MS Access VBA.

He has defined a function like this

```
Function transferTable(tableType As String) As Boolean
```

when the function is called, it looks like that

```
transferTable = True
```

Depending on the argument tableType there are several select case statements. e.g.

```
Select Case tableType
        Case "rc": range = "A" & row & ":AD" & row
        Case "66": range = "A" & row & ":M" & row
        Case "25": range = "A" & row & ":L" & row
        Case "67": range = "A" & row & ":L" & row
        Case "77": range = "A" & row & ":L" & row
        Case "47": range = "A" & row & ":L" & row
        Case "c2": range = "A" & row & ":S" & row
    End Select
```

I just don't understand where we pass a "value" to tableType. I can't find it in the VBA Code and none of the queries/tables contain a column with the name tableType.

Are there any other ways to pass an argument to a function in MS Access VBA? I am still a total newbe to programming...

Comment: Have you looked int he code for `transferTable` `tableType` is the name given to the argument, for use in the proc.  So you can say `strName="Nathan"` and have a proc like so `Function AddToName(strNameInput as string)` and you can call like so `AddToName(strName)` but the code in the proc will refer to `strNameInput`

Comment: When the function is called, it should look like this: `result = transferTable("name")`. The `transferTable = True` is likely just the assignment of the function's return value, taken from within that function's body.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> transferTable = True
> ```

That isn't an invocation of the function. This can only be *within* the function, in a part of the code that assigns the function's return value.

Here's a simple example; this function takes a `Long` parameter and returns `True` if the parameter is greater than 0, `False` otherwise:

```
Public Function MyFunction(ByVal someParameter As Long) As Boolean
    MyFunction = (someParameter > 0)
End Function
```

That's the only place you'll ever see a function's name on the left-hand side of an assignment operator.

Where that function is invoked, the code might look like this:

```
MyFunction 42
```

Or like this:

```
result = MyFunction(42)
```

Or like this:

```
If MyFunction(42) Then
```

And that's how arguments are passed to any `Sub` or `Function` procedure... there is no other way.

Consider this (well-known?) function usage:

```
MsgBox "message"
```

And:

```
result = MsgBox("message", vbYesNo)
```

Or:

```
If MsgBox("message", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
```